# cannot convert from 'const boost::asio::const_buffers_1' to 'boost::asio::mutable_buffer'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
bool Connection::Receive(){
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> buffer(new std::string());

    socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(*buffer), boost::bind(&Connection::handler, this, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    //std::cout<<buffer<<std::endl;

    int recvlen = buffer->length();
    if (recvlen <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    //this->OnReceived(buffer, recvlen);
    return true;
}
```

Error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const boost::asio::const_buffers_1' to 'boost::asio::mutable_buffer'    e:\boost_1_46_1\boost_1_46_1\boost\asio\detail\buffer_sequence_adapter.hpp  211
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async_receive` function need to change the content of the buffer, but you can't change a constant buffer.

Use a `mutable_buffer` instead of a constant buffer. You can find some informations [here](http://www.systomath.com/include/Boost-1_36/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer/mutable_buffer.html)

You need to pass a pointer and the size to the mutable buffer:

```
std::vector<char> content_buffer(max_buffer_size);

... boost::asio::mutable_buffer(content.data(), content.size()) ...
```

It's important that you declare your `content_buffer` in a global scope, bacause the `async_receive` function is accessing the buffer async. If you declare your buffer in the function, it go out of scope before data get received.

Comment: This answer is good but not quite correct. The buffer passed to `async_receive` does not need to be declared at global scope. It should not have automatic storage duration, but dynamic storage duration is just fine. The example used in the OP's question where the buffer's lifetime is managed by a `shared_ptr` will work as long as it stays in scope for the lifetime of the asynchronous operation. This can be achieved by passing the `shared_ptr` as an argument to the bound completion function.

Comment: @Sam Miller thnx for your help :)

Comment: Why are you giving a link to a non-boost related site? Why not give the correct link which is: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/    does your site have some kind of malware on it?

Comment: @Xander: Mirrors are perfectly "correct". A mirror of the Boost documentation is hardly "a non-boost related site".

Comment: It's a Mirror, was the first result on google for the documentation.